# Task instance inside the action delegate

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I cannot use the instance of my task (`t`) within my task's action delegate in my code directly below.  I get the following error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 't'

Code:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(t.Id.ToString());
});
```

Now, it works if I do the following:

```
Task t = null;
t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(t.Id.ToString());
});
```

Could someone please explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# compiler does not know anything about `Task.Factory.StartNew`. As far as the compiler is concerned, the access to `t` could happen at any time after calling `StartNew`, including the time before `t` has been assigned.

Your second code snippet has a race condition: if the task on a concurrent thread gets around to displaying message box before the assignment is complete, you will see a null reference exception.

Try this experiment:

```
private static Task Wrapper(Action f) {
    var res = Task.Factory.StartNew(f);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return res;
}
```

Now replace the direct call of `Task.Factory.StartNew` with a call of `Wrapper` in your second snippet, and watch the program crash.

```
Task t = null;
t = Wrapper(() => {
    MessageBox.Show(t.Id.ToString());
});
```

Comment: Both snippets (in the question) have the same race condition. But the compiler doesn't know, the error is from a static analysis.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, it is still there. The idea was to make race condition more pronounced.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.  So, is there a safe way of accessing my task's instance in the delegate?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Oh, I see what you mean, you are absolutely right. The static analyzer of the compiler sees a possibility of using an unassigned variable, and reports an error.

Comment: @davenewza One way to make sure there is no race condition would be to add synchronization between the main thread and the task: create a `ManualResetEvent` before declaring the task, wait for the event inside the task, and signal the event after the task has been assigned.

Answer (score 2):

You must assign a value to t first, so that it gets a reference to an object of type Task.

In you first bit of code you try to assign a value to t and use it in one statement (only one semi-colon there).

In the second example these are two separate statements, so it will work.